# Toggle Number of Date Pickers with Dropdown list

Tags: javascript, for-loop, input, datepicker, addeventlistener

I have a small dropdown list of numbers from 0 to 4 (I could add more), e.g. number 4 is 4 years worth of data.
If I choose 4, I get 4 rows of date pickers for the user to choose a start and end date.

It uses a for loop, and works, but the problem is I can't redo the number of date pickers with the dropdown menu.

Here is my code. Note I'm using Python Flask, hence the form action="{{url_for.."
otherwise it would be form aciton = "some url link.."

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>Dates</title>
</head>
<body>


<form action="{{url_for('home')}}">
<ul id = "loop-list">

</ul>

<input type="submit"> 
</form>

<select>
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
</select>
Change value of the select to show the value.
<p>
</p>


<script type="text/javascript">


var res = document.querySelector("p");
var select = document.querySelector("select");

var length;

var loopList = document.getElementById("loop-list");

var unselect = document.getElementById("loop-list");


res.textContent =  "Selected Value: " + select.value;

var boolean = false;
var currentSelect;

select.addEventListener("change", function(e){
    res.textContent = "Selected Value: " + select.value;

    currentSelect = select.value;
    length = parseInt(select.value);


if(boolean == false & length !=0){
    for(var i =0; i < length; i++){

        loopList.innerHTML += "<li>Date "  + (i+1) + 
        " <input type='date' name='bday' max='2018-10-01'>Enter a date<input type='date' name='bday' min='2019-12-31'></li><br>";


    }
    boolean = true;

}

});

unselect.addEventListener("change", function(w){

    res.textContent = "Selected Value: " + unselect.value;

    length = parseInt(unselect.value);


if(boolean == true & length != 0){

    for(var i = 0; i < length; i++){

        loopList.innerHTML -="<li>Date "  + (i+1) + 
        " <input type='date' name='bday' max='2018-10-01'>Enter a date<input type='date' name='bday' min='2019-12-31'></li><br>";

    }
    boolean = false;
}
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

So if I have 4 rows of date pickers; start and end dates, respectively, how can I essentially toggle it to only displaying 3,2, 1 or 0 rows of date pickers by reusing the dropdown menu?

Hope I've worded my question properly. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm sure it's something relatively simple.
You could drop the unselect.addEventListener("change"... but that is there to stop the dropdown menu/list from displaying more than the maximum number of 4 rows of date pickers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need 2 listeners for this. What you can do is, reset your HTML on `change` and add the selected number of date pickers.

```js
var res = document.querySelector("p");
var select = document.querySelector("select");

var loopList = document.getElementById("loop-list");

res.textContent = "Selected Value: " + select.value;

select.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
  res.textContent = "Selected Value: " + select.value;

  var length = parseInt(select.value);
  loopList.innerHTML = ""; //Reset the HTML tag where date pickers will be added
  
  if (length != 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      loopList.innerHTML += "<li>Date " + (i + 1) +
        " <input type='date' name='bday' max='2018-10-01'>Enter a date<input type='date' name='bday' min='2019-12-31'></li><br>";
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<form>
  <ul id="loop-list"></ul>
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<select>
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
Change value of the select to show the value.
<p></p>
```

Comment: Thanks Prerak! Works perfectly fine now :)

Comment: Happy to help :)